# Why does my batch file make a copy of a copy?

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have a basic batch file which copies everything to another folder:

```
@echo off
set list=%dir%*.jpg
mkdir Converted
for %%f in (%list%) do ( 
   echo Copying "%%f"
   copy "%%f" "Converted\x_%%~nf.jpg"
)
```

It seems to work but for some reason creates an additional copy of the first file.

input:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
```

output:

```
x_1.jpg
x_2.jpg
x_3.jpg
x_x_1.jpg
```

How can I prevent it creating x_x_1.jpg?

Answer (score 0):

It makes a copy because it's locating the copied file when you use `*.jpg`

The normal method around this is to use

```
for /f "delims=" %%e in ('dir /b /a-d "%dir%\*.jpg') do ...
```

which performs a directory listing (`/b` in basic form - just filenames `/a-d` o directorynames) THEN processes that list to `%%e`

Note that you would need to prefix both the source and destination filenames with `%dir%\` using this method, as it processes filenames.

Recommendation re standard SO batch practice:

- Use `set "var=value" to set variables. This syntax ensures trailing spaces on program lines are not included in the value assigned.
- Don't include `"` or trailing `\` in variables. Much easier to control directoryname construction
- Don't use command names (like `dir`) as variable names, labels or filenames. Avoids confusion